# Configure in TableView is not being reached

Tags: swift, uitableview

So I am trying to have a TableView displayed, but I'm currently only getting an empty tableview. Upon further inspection, I see that the `configure` block is not being run. Why is this?

Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: teamCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    print("reached")
    
    func configure(cell: UITableViewCell,
                   for indexPath: IndexPath) {

     print("not reached")
      guard let cell = cell as? TeamCell else {
          return
      }

      let team = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
      cell.teamLabel.text = team.teamName
      cell.scoreLabel.text = "Wins: \(team.wins)"

      if let imageName = team.imageName {
        cell.flagImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
      } else {
        cell.flagImageView.image = nil
      }
    }
    return cell
  }
}
```

TeamCell

```
class TeamCell: UITableViewCell {
  // MARK: - IBOutlets
  @IBOutlet weak var teamLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var flagImageView: UIImageView!

  // MARK: - View Life Cycle
  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    teamLabel.text = nil
    scoreLabel.text = nil
    flagImageView.image = nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `configure(cell:for:)`?

Comment: It's a method, but you don't call it (also, I don't know why it's inside cellForRow). It's like the difference between) `func someName(of: String)`, and `someName(of: "someValue")`. You aren't calling it.

Comment: Hi Ajnauleau, did you add the tabeView delegates & datasource via storyboard or in your view controller? Without these two, the table "view" will be empty and none of the delegate and datasource methods with be called!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your tableView is empty or it looks like empty and your tableView methods are not being called are two reasons.

1)- Table view heigh or width is equal to 0 and there is no need to load and display tableView, respectively tableView cell.

2)- You did not connect tableView data source and delegates to your view controller.

2.1) You can add TableView delegates and data sources through storyboard (see image down below)

[image]

[image]

2.2) You can add TableView delegates and data sources thrugh code in your view controller, like:

2.2.1) In viewDidLoad() method:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// TableView Delegates & DataSource
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

2.2.2) Or view tableView outlet didSet (I prefer this way, if I don't do it via storyboard):

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a structure like this:

```
// This next line defines a function called a
func a() {
    print("a")
    
    // This next line only defines a function called b:
    // that is scoped inside the 'a' function
    func b() {
      print("b")
    }

    // Defining a function does not invoke the function
    // That would need an actual call here like this:
    // b()
}

// I can't call b here because it's nested inside the function 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have a nested func inside function?
Take it out....
then after this line :

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: teamCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
```

do this:

```
configure(cell: cell,for indexPath: indexPath)
```